# xmlHttpRequest not sending files from plupload library

Tags: xmlhttprequest, debian, send, plupload

I have recently upgraded my debian from 7.1 to 8.1. I tried several versions of plupload but none of them is sending files that I upload from a form. My actual version of plupload is 2.1.2, and it is supposed to create a file in `/tmp/` with 'php' prefix from `xmlHttpRequest.send(FormData)`. There are no errors, it just doesn't create the tmp file (I know it unlinks when the script finished, but file is still not created).

Edit: mistery resolved, it creates the files inside a new folder inside /tmp/ with a long weird name, and inside that folder were another /tmp/ folder where the files were created

Edit2: I dunno how to mark this question as resolved :S Thanks

Comment: Please provide some examples of your code, it'll increase probability of getting a correct answer to your question.

Comment: Could you provide an example for this?

Comment: is not my code, is on plupload212/plupload.full.min.js and is not readable

Comment: but if u want u can see https://area51.phpbb.com/code-changes/3.1.0/side-by-side/3.1.11/phpbb-assets-plupload-plupload.full.min.js.html and search for h.send(r), will be in the code of the left, and h is a xmlHttpRequest instance